# Why does Angular HttpClient replace "+" with "↵"

Tags: javascript, angular, x-www-form-urlencoded

when I try to make an encrypted HTTP POST angular replace "+" with " " how can I solve this?

```
const body = new HttpParams()
    .set('name', nameGroup)
    .set('enterprise', workspacesGroup)
    .set('id', id)

    this.http.post('API-TEST-URL', body.toString(), {

      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'charset=UTF-8')
    }).subscribe(async (res:any) => {
      if (res.status == 'OK') {
        console.log(res);
      }
      
      
    })
```

Comment: Because `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` *does* encode spaces as `+` (optionally `%20`), and `+` as `%2B`. Maybe your decoding is broken?

Comment: What would be the best solution for it? :c

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What values do you send, and where exactly do you get the wrong result?

Comment: For example I send this "U2FsdGVkX19O+PUMawwb1L1+8j+yx9pMUOeHAEtUjTh/iGIGmSjlksizo12lakd+Ams+DG8TNcnEQ6/QLw==" And the backend received this: "U2FsdGVkX19O 
 PUMawwb1L1 
 8j  yx9pMUOeHAEtUjTh/iGIGmSjlksizo12lakd  Ams  DG8TNcnEQ6/QLw=="

Comment: @Bergi This is an example

Comment: What value do you see in the browser's network monitor?

Comment: That looks like a base64-encoded value, not an url-encoded one. How do you send this? Please post the output of `body.toString()`.

Comment: Btw, [`HttpHeaders.set`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#set) takes only two arguments but you're passing three